# How to save file data from POST variable and load it back to response in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I have a such problem - I am using Python 2.6 / Django 1.3 and I need to **accept as POST variable with key 'f', which contains a binary data**. After that, I need to **save data** in a file.

**POST**

```
T$topX$objectsX$versionY$archiverО©ҐR$0О©ҐО©ҐО©Ґull_=<---------------------- content of file -------------------->О©ҐО©Ґ_NSKeyedArchive(258:=CО©ҐО©Ґ
```

**Code**

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def save(request):
    upload_file = request.POST['f']
    save_path = default_storage.save('%s%s' % (save_dir, filename),
        ContentFile(upload_file))
```

When I am trying to do

```
nano /tmp/myfile.zip
```

It returns data like

```
T^@^@^@$^@^@^@t^@^@^@o^@^@^@p^@^@^@X^@^@^@$^@^@^@o^@^@^@b^@^@^@j^@^@^@e^@^@^@c^@^@^@t^@^@^@s^@^@^@X^@^@^@$^@^@^@v^@^@^@e^@^@^@r^@^@^@s^@^@^@i^@^@$
```

When its done, I am going to **read saved file**

```
def read(request):
    user_file = default_storage.open(file_path).read()
    file_name = get_filename(file_path)
    response = HttpResponse(user_file, content_type = 'text/plain', 
               mimetype = 'application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % file_name
    response['Content-Length'] = default_storage.size(file_path)

    return response
```

In case, when I am writing

```
print user_file
```

It returns a correct data, but when I am returning a HttpResponse it has a different data from a source

Comment: You should serve out the URI of the file, and let a real webserver (eg. Apache) serve static files. Also note that it is strongly recommended to check the uploaded file before saving, as far as security is concerned.

Comment: In this situation I just need to accept data, save and return it after a while. Please, could you be so kind to suggest me a solution?

Comment: Only one solution I am able to find at the moment:

- after saving a file return a link to that file in a local filesystem
- client (i.e. flash or something) will ask nginx for a static file

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier, and more memory efficient if you just save the data into a file, and like @keckse said, let a browser stream it. Django is very inefficient in streaming data. It will all depend on the size of the data. If you want to stream it with django anyways, it can be done like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os.path
import mimetypes


def stream(request, document, type=None):
    doc = Document.objects.get(pk=document)

    fsock = open(doc.file.path,"r")

    file_name = os.path.basename(doc.file.path)
    mime_type_guess = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
    if mime_type_guess is not None:
        response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype=mime_type_guess[0])

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + file_name
    return response
```

In your case you might want to set the mime type manually, you can try out application/octet-stream too. The mainpassing iterators difference is that you pass the "string" from file.read(), instead of the handle to the file directly. Please note: if you use read(), you will be loading the whole file into memory.

More on [passing iterators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators) to HttpResonse. And I might be wrong, but I think you can drop the [content-type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__).